# Why does the mortar and brick crack under corner of window?

Tags: crack

my house is only 5 year old and recently i have been seeing cracks in mortar and brick under the corner of the windows around the house. these crack start from the corner where the window is and goes downwards. what can cause these cracks? who should i call to help here? like structural engineer or foundation expert or someone to fix windows?
[image: Crack under window]

Comment: Is that your own DIY re-pointing we can see? Pointing is not going to prevent movement & re-cracking. As the house is only 5 years old you should grab the guarantee & get the construction company to come out & take measurements, put in movement markers etc to see if it's just a normal bit of settling, or something more insidious.

Comment: They might be just hairline cracks for now, but a indication of something to come. Anything to see inside ?

Comment: Whereabout in the world are you located? Is that wall a "real" brick wall (European-style) or is a veneer brick wall over wooden studs (American-style)?

Comment: i am in north west arkansas .. its a veneer brick wall

Comment: Be careful to use the correct mortar. We design these walls using mortar that is weaker than the brick. That way, when and if, there is a problem, it’s easier to fix cracked mortar (repointing) than it is to fix cracked brick (replacement with matching color, size, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this appears to be a normal "settling" crack in the brick veneer on your home.  It's not a structural problem and, in fact, it not much or a problem at all.  What you want to do is to seal the crack with some grout or caulk to prevent water infiltration and keep on eye on it over time.

These cracks start at window and other opening corners because these are the weakest and/or least supported areas of the wall.  A solid brick wall is much stronger than one that has openings in it but for homes, usually we want windows and doors.  So it's a compromise.

Comment: thnx @jwh20 for checking. i have tried applying mortar on it but it keeps reappearing on top of mortar agaain and it is coming on multiple window and same like this in corners only. i will take your word and try to apply grout on it again. i was worried as i have never seen anything like this on the houses and this being only 5 year old house worries me a more

Comment: @Jack you need to try to make that crack a little wider so that you can get some flexible grout or caulk *into* the crack and not just over the surface.